# Stubbing key/value pair in ruby on rails ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test the effect of the value of an ENV key on my code. I am stubbing this by using

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('ADWORDS_RUN').and_return('No')
```

This was working until I changed the target code to include accessing another ENV key. The target code now includes the following

```
 def not_local_machine?
    !ENV['LOCAL_MACHINE']
 end
```

The test now fails in the above function with the error message

```
 Failure/Error: get 'home'
   ENV received :[] with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("ADWORDS_RUN")
          got: ("LOCAL_MACHINE")
    Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

It appears that my current method of stubbing is wiping out other ENV keys. How do I stub an ENV key to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
stub_const 'ENV', ENV.to_h.merge('ADWORDS_RUN' => 'No')
```

Comment: I tried this and received an error that ```merge``` is not defined for ```ENV```. The class of ```ENV``` is object.  This looks close to the right answer, any ideas on how to implement the merge?

Comment: @Obromios, I just added `.to_h` after `ENV` to convert it to a hash before merging. That should work.

Comment: Close, just need to change :ENV to 'ENV', see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant. I have edited your answer accordingly, and if the edit is accepted, then will accept your answer.

Comment: `Object.stub_const(:ENV, ENV.to_hash.merge("ENV_NAME" => "value"))`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved that issue:

```
before { allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).and_call_original }

context 'ADWORDS_RUN is No' do
  before { allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('ADWORDS_RUN').and_return('No') }

  [example block]
end
```

(Aside, I recommend using something like 'false' instead of 'No'.)

Answer (score 0):

For [modifying ENV's in tests](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/testing-and-environment-variables), Thoughtbot's [climate_control](https://github.com/thoughtbot/climate_control) gem is worth a look.

You wrap your test around `ClimateControl` block to control temporary changes to ENV values. Using your example:

```rb
ClimateControl.modify ADWORDS_RUN: 'No' do
  expect(AdwordsTask.new.run?).to eq(false)
end
```

To use with RSpec, you could define this in your spec:

```rb
def with_modified_env(options, &block)
  ClimateControl.modify(options, &block)
end
```

This would allow for more straightforward way to modify/stub environment values:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdwordsTask, 'name' do
  it 'does not run adwords' do
    with_modified_env ADWORDS_RUN: 'No' do
      expect(AdwordsTask.new.run?).to eq(false)
    end
  end

  def with_modified_env(options, &block)
    ClimateControl.modify(options, &block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding/overwriting the `[]` method of ENV. The original meaning is gone completely.

Check out https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks and look for the chapter "Arbitrary Handling". It contains this sample code:

```
expect(double).to receive(:msg) do |arg|
  expect(arg.size).to eq 7
end
```

You should be able to adopt that for your needs... something along the lines of (untested)

```
dummy_env = { ADWORDS_RUN: 1, LOCAL_MACHINE: 2 }
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]) do |key|
  dummy_env[key] or raise "#{key} not expected"
end
```

Or if you want to keep all old ENV entries

```
env_clone = ENV.clone
allow... do|key|
   dummy_env[key] or env_clone[key]
end
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not work, it returns nil instead of the stubbed value of the key.  Looking at the api http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ENV.html, it seems that the method ```key``` does not return the value of the key, so perhaps this approach needs a different receiver?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed the answer. I meant `receive(:[])` instead of `receive(:key)`.

Comment: When I try that, I get an error ```Failure/Error: dummy_env[key] or ENV[key]
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep```.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, if you use `ENV[key]` inside the override for `ENV[key]` you get a recursion. Edited again. But really, I just wanted to point you on the way, don't bother with it if the other answer is acceptable to you.